# SQL Server more columns than group by

Tags: sql, sql-server, group-by

I have the following example tables

```
Employee (EmpID, DepID)
Order (OrderID, EMpID, description)
```

What I'm trying to achieve is to select employees with most orders by department. I'm on it for like 4 hours already and can't find resolution to this perhaps easy problem.
All I get is either number of order by employee or max number of orders by one employee in one department but I'm struggling to get result as:

```
DepID, EmpID, Number of orders
```

Comment: What does your current query look like?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's my solution for you :

```
WITH Temp AS (
  SELECT
      emp.EMpID   
     ,emp.DepID
     ,COUNT(OrderId) nb_order
     ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY emp.DepID ORDER BY COUNT(OrderId) DESC) Ordre
  FROM
     Order ord
  INNER JOIN
     Employee emp
        ON emp.EmpID = ord.EmpID
GROUP BY  
   emp.EMpID
  ,emp.DepID)


SELECT *
FROM Temp
WHERE Ordre = 1
```

I hope this will help you :)

Comment: Hope too, gonna test in few mmins. I thought something about that row_number, over and partition by thingy but i cant seem to understand it too much - if that would work then im definetly gonna take a look how it works excatly

Comment: Okeeey :)..i will be right in front of the screen hhh

Comment: Awesome! That totally worked thank youuuu! Im so glad i decided to ask question here as alone id fight with it at least for a week yet, but it took you just a minute or two ;] Well of i go to read about that OVER and Partion by. Once again thanks!! :)

Comment: Woow glad to help too!! I am happy for you, just don't hesitate to ask question directly if you wan't